# Layout inflate exception for fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, expandablelistview

I am trying to put 2 fragments in an activity,the bottom fragment is giving the layout inflate exception.please help me resolving this,i am stuck with this.this works fine when i put a list view but its not working for expandable list view

```
    activity_main.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.mindtree.calenderevents.MainActivity">


        <fragment
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.mindtree.calenderevents.TopSectionFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="111dp"
            tools:layout="@layout/top_section_fragment" />

        <fragment
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:name="com.mindtree.calenderevents.BottomSectionFragment"
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            tools:layout="@layout/bottom_fragment"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

top_section_fragment.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/get_events"
            android:id="@+id/getEventsButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="updateDisplay"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

bottom_fragment.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lvExp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

this is my MainActivity where i get permissions for reading calender and get events for current day and display the title of the events

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TopSectionFragment.GetAllEvents {
    private static final int WRITE_CALENDER = 1;
    private static final int READ_CALENDER = 2;
    Calendar c;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TopSectionFragment fragment = TopSectionFragment.newInstance();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void getEvents() {

        //TODO: implement method to fetch events from calendar and add as fragment arguments
        getPermissionToReadCalender();

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case READ_CALENDER: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.

                    RuntimeData.setsCalendarData(getCalender(null));
                    if (RuntimeData.getsCalendarData() != null) {
                        BottomSectionFragment bottomFragment = new BottomSectionFragment();
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2,
                                bottomFragment).commit();
                    }

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    private void getPermissionToReadCalender() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR)) {
            }
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR},
                    READ_CALENDER);

        }else{
            RuntimeData.setsCalendarData(getCalender(null));
            if (RuntimeData.getsCalendarData() != null) {

                BottomSectionFragment bottomFragment = new BottomSectionFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment2,
                        bottomFragment).commit();
            }
        }

    }

    protected CalendarData getCalender(View view) {
        String[] projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION};
        c = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());

        String splittedDate[] = formattedDate.split("[-\\s]");

        for (int i = 0; i < splittedDate.length; i++) {

        }
        int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[0]);
        int currentMonth = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[1]);
        int currentDay = Integer.parseInt(splittedDate[2]);
        String currentTime = splittedDate[3];
        String splittedTime[] = currentTime.split(":");
        int currentHour = Integer.parseInt(splittedTime[0]);
        int currentMin = Integer.parseInt(splittedTime[1]);

        // 0 = January, 1 = February, ...

        Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startTime.set(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, 12, 0, currentMin);
        // startTime.set(2016,9,26,2,00);
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, 24, 00);

// the range is all data from 2016

        String selection = "(( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + startTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= " + endTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ))";

        Cursor cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

// output the events

        CalendarData mCalendarData = new CalendarData();
        ArrayList<String> eventTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> eventDescription = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> eventLocation = new ArrayList<String>();
        //  assert cursor != null;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

             //   Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Title: " + cursor.getString(1) + " Start-Time: " + (new Date(cursor.getLong(3))).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                eventTitle.add(cursor.getString(1));
                eventDescription.add(cursor.getString(2));
                eventLocation.add(cursor.getString(6));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            mCalendarData.setEventTitle(eventTitle);
            mCalendarData.setEventDesc(eventDescription);
            mCalendarData.setEventLoc(eventLocation);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "no events for today", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return mCalendarData;
    }

}
```

TopSectionFragment.java

```
public class TopSectionFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {

    private GetAllEvents mEventListener;

    public static TopSectionFragment newInstance() {
        TopSectionFragment fragment = new TopSectionFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public TopSectionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mEventListener = (GetAllEvents) activity;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_section_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Button eventsButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.getEventsButton);
        eventsButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.getEventsButton:

                updateDisplay( view);
                break;

        }
    }

 protected void updateDisplay(View view) {



     mEventListener.getEvents();
    }

    public interface GetAllEvents {
        void getEvents();
    }
}
```

BottomSectionFragment.java

```
public class BottomSectionFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private CalendarData mData=new CalendarData();

    ArrayList<String> mEventDesc;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_fragment,container,false);


        if (RuntimeData.getsCalendarData()!=null){

            mData = RuntimeData.getsCalendarData();

        }
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mEventDesc=mData.getEventTitle();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mEventDesc);


        if(mEventDesc!=null) {
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

this is the stack trace that i am getting

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.mindtree.calenderevents, PID: 14450
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mindtree.calenderevents/com.mindtree.calenderevents.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                     at com.mindtree.calenderevents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                     at com.mindtree.calenderevents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:346)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:147)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1268)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1370)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2415)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:376)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                     at com.mindtree.calenderevents.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: share java code of activity.......

Comment: which activity..main activity..? because i have 2 fragment activities and a main activity

Comment: i have updated the question with stack trace please let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: Main Activity...................

Comment: yaa updated my post with all the code

Comment: resolved it by putting fill_parent in bottom_fragment.xml        so the bottom fragment looks like this                                                               `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>`